# How to call my jquery function in an html.erb file from a js.erb file in the same view folder

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a draw function that runs on page load, here is the `html.erb file` excerpt:

```
<div class="canvasarea">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="360" height="840"></canvas>
</div>

<script> 
//definition of vars used in draw function...

 window.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(drawSomething,500)
  };

  function drawSomething() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, xOffset, yOffset);
  }  
 </script>
```

I want to redraw this image when a button is pushed on the page.  That button lives in an html.erb file.  It currently replaces some `tr`s.  I want to call the `drawSomething()` function when the button is pressed.  The `.js.erb file`:

```
<% @pos_range.each do |p|%>
    $("td#add_foo_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bars/update_foo_position', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :position_str => @position_str, :position => p} ))%>");
    <% if (@foo and p == @foo.position) or @pos_range.length == 1 %>
        $("td#add_foo_button_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bars/update_foo_position_button', :locals => { :id => @bar.id, :position_str => @position_str, :position => p} ))%>");
    <% else %>
        $("td#add_foo_button_<%= p %>").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bars/update_foo_position_empty', :locals => { :id => @bar.id, :position_str => @position_str, :position => p} ))%>");
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @foo%>
    $("#tr_<%=@foo.name %>").hide()
<% end %>
$("#dialog").dialog("close").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById("yourbuttonid");
button.addEventListener("click", drawSomething, false);
```

Or jquery syntax

```
$("#yourbuttonid").on("click",function(){
    drawSomething();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working exactly right.  Only part of the image is being redraws.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to be called after replacing the elements and closing the dialog, you should be able to simple add this to the end of your `js.erb` file:

```
drawSomething();
```